# How to run python script from computer and do to the file in flash drive

Tags: 18.04, python, paths

I have Python script that will read file "Customer_List" ,operate it, and write it back to `Customer_List` again.
It's running well on Windows but I want to know how to run it on Ubuntu I need to run this python script from hard disk and read a .txt file in a flash drive

**Update 09/08/19**

I have done Mr. cmak.fr's suggestion:

1. I have renamed the python file to billywork.py
2. I have changed the first line and the Customer_List file path

   ```
   #!/home/thanapong/Desktop/billywork

   if a == 0:
   data = pd.read_csv("/media/thanapong/F91B-8B18/Customer_List.txt", header=0)
   query = data.loc[data['NAME']==lookfor]
   if not query.empty:
    print(query)
    data.loc[data['NAME']==lookfor, 'SCORE'] = (query.SCORE - 1)
    print()
    print(data.loc[data['NAME']==lookfor])
    data.to_csv("/media/thanapong/F91B-8B18/Customer_List.txt", index=None)
   else:
    print('Not found')
   ```
3. I used `whereis` command but it didn't give me a directory of file, so I draged billywork.py in the  terminal and used that fullpath and do same thing with Customer_List.When I ran `chmod +x` , it don't do anything.Then I ran `python billywork.py`, but it still gives error.

   [image]

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you please instead of posting a screenshot of the script text and the datafile put this as formatted codeblocks in your question by [edit]ing it. If you have trouble on how to format in here you can refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't run `whereis billywork` but `whereis python`. This should give you something like `/usr/bin/python`. This `/usr/bin/python` (or what is in your case) is what  you must add in the first line right after the `#!` (instead of `/home/thanapong/Desktop/billywork`.)

Comment: As for `chmod +x`, this doesn't give any output. It just changes the file's permissions so it can be executed. To see if it worked, you run `ls -l` in your terminal. Your file should be colored green and on the left of it you should see something like `-rwxr--r--`. The `x` means that it is executable, so `chmod +x` worked.

Comment: I run  `whereis python`  and it's give me this  `thanapong@thanapong-Lenovo-C360:~$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/lib/python3.6 /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python3.6 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /usr/local/lib/python3.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.6m /usr/share/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz` , what should i put at the first line?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python`.  However you don't even need this (it is called shebang) if you run your file using the `python` command (`python billyworks.py`). Take a look on this tutorial: https://realpython.com/run-python-scripts/

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I didn't read cmark.fr's answer carefully enough to see that he already takes into account that your script is on the Desktop. Now, if your script doesn't work correctly, this isn't the right place to ask for help. You better ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: replace the first line `#!/home/thanapong/Desktop/billywork` with `#!/usr/bin/python` then make it executable `chmod +x ~/Desktop/billywork.py` and run your script with `~/Desktop/billywork.py` or `python ~/Desktop/billywork.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Please copy/paste all texts instead of posting screenshots)*

All the issues you are facing are related to the pathes of files
The python script `python.py` should be named with something else than 'python'. There is no issue with this name **but** since the python interpreter is named 'python', this can be disturbing

The python script `billywork.py` is located on the desktop
`~/Desktop/billywork.py`

**To make it executable**

*OPTIONAL Shebang* :
- Edit the first line to specify the path to the python interpreter
`#!/usr/bin/python` is for generic python interpreter version
You can get the path of a program with the command `whereis` as `whereis python`
This optional line is called the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))
*The #! syntax used in scripts to indicate an interpreter for execution*
With a (correct) shebang and an executable script you can run it simply by typing `/path/to/script.py`, in you case `~/Desktop/billywork.py`

Without shebang, the script have to be called as paremeter of the interpreter program. That is `python ~/Desktop/billywork`
- Make the `billywork.py` script executable
`chmod +x ~/Desktop/python.py`

**`Customer_List.txt` file location**
Get the full path of the file by dragging and drop the file to a terminal window
`/media/thanapong/F91B-8B18/Customer_List.txt` is the full path of the text file
Edit the python script parts where the file location should stand.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing and  this suggestion.I have done it, but it still error or I have done some mistake please take a look.I just edit the post.